# do not redirect the user if redirect address is the same as the current address

Tags: hyperlinks

Would it be a good idea to not redirect the user if the clicked anchor tag address is the same as the current address of the user?

e.g. If user is currently at `//example.com/home` and he clicks a link to `//example.com/home` do not redirect the user.

What are the Pros and Cons for good user experience. Thanks

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why is there a link to the current page?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21729/why-is-there-a-link-to-the-current-page)

Comment: At least related, if not duplicate: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55627/should-clicking-the-logo-for-a-website-while-on-the-home-page-reload-the-page

Answer (score 2):

A few reasons why you should load the page (redirect) if a user clicks an anchor to the currently viewed page:

1. A user might be using this functionality to reload the page (instead of pressing F5/reload)
2. A user might think the link is broken if nothing happens when they click it.

So the answer is, it's **not** a good idea to not redirect - i.e. don't remove the default behaviour of clicking the link.

If there is a reason that you don't want to reload the same page then remove the link completely from the page or disable it.